# Text Rendering Problem with Distance Field in WebGL

Tags: opengl, webgl

I made this Distance Field example with Qt OpenGL 3.3:

[image: https://community.khronos.org/uploads/default/original/2X/b/b323d50a78a572bc3f132dcd4b732acd5c2e13cf.gif]

It works very good. I made it using this video tutorial: [OpenGL 3D Game Tutorial 33: Distance Field Text Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8cfgcJR9Tk)

I rewrote this example line by line in WebGL and it looks bad:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem related to [Premultiplied Alpha](https://wiki.animation-luzern.ch/Premultiplied_Alpha) (see [Why does my WebGL alpha-transparency look wrong?](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/08/12/why-does-my-webgl-alpha-transparency-look-wrong/).

You need to multiply the color channels by the alpha channel in the fragment shader:

```c
void main() {
    // [...]

    vec4 color = ...;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * color.a, color.a);
}
```

and change the blend function to *1 * source_color + (1 -alpha) * dest_color*:

```js
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that was made by **_Develop**:

```
const options: WebGLContextAttributes = {
    alpha: false, premultipliedAlpha: false
}
gl = (canvas as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext("webgl", options);
```

```
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

const float width = 0.5;
const float edge = 0.1;

void main()
{
    float distance = 1.0 - texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord).a;
    float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(width, width + edge, distance);
    if (alpha < 0.001)
    {
        discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.2, 0.5, 0.0, alpha);
}
```